# Invoke modal view controller from UIWebView weblink

Tags: view, uiwebview, hyperlink, modal-dialog

Hey folks I was wondering if anyone can tip me on a painless way of invoking a modal view controller from a web link in a UIWebView.  Is it possible to do this?

I want the modal view controller to still be a part of the app as opposed to closing the main app and using a helper application instead.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is by intercepting certain URLs in the UIWebView's delegate function

```
– webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:
```

This can be called from javascript by setting the window's location:

```
window.location = "mycomprotocall:showMoadViewController";
```

Parse this in the delegate function, then execute any native code you like.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using vanilla webpages that can be accessed from safari mobile, it is not possible. If you're programming a local webapp with phonegap or similar technologies, it is fairly easy, just catch the urls you want and handle them differently.